# Google talk makes sounds even when my laptop is muted

Tags: windows-xp, audio, thinkpad, mute

This is very strange.
I have my laptop on mute. The mute works for almost everything (as it should), but when I get Google Talk messages, it makes a sound!
I have Windows XP running on Lenovo x200.
Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: What method are you using to mute your speakers? Are you just muting a certain device/channel or are you certain that it's the hardware mute?

Comment: I'm muting via the mute button on my laptop, and I also see that it's muted in the speaker icon on the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hlrm=nl&answer=23957. It looks like Google Talk unmutes the speakers on an incoming call.

> ### Ringing occurs when speakers are on 'Mute'
>
> If you don't want Google Talk to automatically
> unmute your speakers when a call is
> coming in, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click 'Settings' at the top of your Friends list.
> 2. Highlight 'Audio' along the left side of the dialogue box, and uncheck
>    the box next to 'Unmute speaker and
>    microphone when on a call.'
> 3. Click 'OK.'
>
> If you disable this option, make sure
> to manually unmute your speakers when
> you're ready to receive calls.

Comment: This doesn't work. Also, I'm talking about an arriving message, not call (if it matters).